# Element see if refresh page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

enter code hereI don't know how to ask this question correct.
I've got some html example:

```
<a ng-click="OpenSubgroups(group)" class="{{group.Ico}}" href="" id="{{group.Id}}" title="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{group.Text}}</a>
```

When I reloaded page I see on this element this `{{group.Ico}}` / `{{group.Id}}`
When page loaded I see correct information. Only 1 sec before page loaded.
How I can hide this from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called as ngCloak

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Just Use directive/Class.

Working JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzwt8hkm/

Template

```
 <span ng-cloak class='ng-cloak'> <b>{{name}}</b> in uppercase <b>{{nameUpper}}</b></span>
```

CSS :

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do this on my example.
Because I've got the same problem with ng-show = "false" html elem. When reload page I see it.

Comment: I made it. And when my page ready. I need take this element and remove class="ng-cloak" right?

Comment: @VolodymyrKozlov no ng-cloak directive will take care of it

Comment: prepare a plunkr or JSfiddle !

Comment: I understand what I doing wrong. Thank. For help. All worked right.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand how work this derective.